# Adaptive card to show table

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to show an adaptive card in Microsoft Bot Composer with the template below to show a table with one column.

````
> To learn more Adaptive Cards format, read the documentation at
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots
- ```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${isArray($dialog.api_response.content)}",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${dialog.api_response.statusCode}",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder"
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "${description}",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": ${dialog.api_response.content}
}
````

Here is what shows in the console for debugging:
`${dialog.api_response.content}`

```
[
{"description": "Information about Renewal application"},
{"description": "Information about Initial application"},
{"description": "Information about my reactivation application status"}
]
```

The output shows nothing, not even the length of array that I am trying to print. Can someone please show if they have used adaptive cards for similar reason with success?

Thank you.

Comment: can all the maintainers please clarify if they are considering to abandon this project and suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Composer uses Web Chat as a base for the chat client. This is a known issue in webchat and won't be available for Composer until it is working in Web Chat. This can be monitored here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4626

Comment: Thank you, any other alternative to show table as chat response.

Comment: I tried with version 1.3 of Adaptive Cards - which includes FactSet. However, even that is not getting rendered in the Bot Framework.